# ReactJS. How to remove event listener inside created listener?

Tags: reactjs, addeventlistener

`onDragEnd` event listens for `touchend` or `mouseup`. If `onDragEnd` function is triggered then `touchmove` and `mousemove` should be removed, but it does not work. How to correctly remove `mousemove` or `touchmove` events after `touchend` or `mouseup` is called?

Source:

```
const onDragEnd = () => {
    window.removeEventListener('touchmove', handleTouchMove);
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
    setIsDragging(false);
    setTranslate(0);
  };

  const handleMouseDown = event => {
    onDragStart(event.clientX);
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
  };

  const handleTouchStart = event => {
    const touch = event.targetTouches[0];
    onDragStart(touch.clientX);
    window.addEventListener('touchmove', handleTouchMove);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('touchend', onDragEnd);
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', onDragEnd);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('touchend', onDragEnd);
      window.removeEventListener('mouseup', onDragEnd);
    };
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the **same reference of the function** to `removeEventListener` that you used to `addEventListener`.

Now since your functions are within functional component and may set state, new reference of the functions are created and hence events are not properly removed.

You can make use of useCallback to memoize the function references which will help in removing the events

```
const handleTouchMove = useCallback(() => {
  }, []);
  const handleMouseMove = useCallback(() => {

  }, [])
  const onDragEnd = useCallback(() => {
    window.removeEventListener('touchmove', handleTouchMove);
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
    setIsDragging(false);
    setTranslate(0);
  }, []);

  const handleMouseDown = useCallback(event => {
    onDragStart(event.clientX);
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
  }, []);

  const handleTouchStart = useCallback(event => {
    const touch = event.targetTouches[0];
    onDragStart(touch.clientX);
    window.addEventListener('touchmove', handleTouchMove);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('touchend', onDragEnd);
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', onDragEnd);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('touchend', onDragEnd);
      window.removeEventListener('mouseup', onDragEnd);
    };
  }, []);
```